# Making better smoothie?

Tags: food

Everyday I make smoothie for my breakfast. Usually, I add some liquid first and then my protein powder and rest all. But everyday once I add the powder, some of it sticks to the wall of the jar and won't mix.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This should prevent the protein powder from getting stuck to the walls of the jar:

1. Pour in your liquid.
2. Add everything else (fruit, ice cubes, etc.) but don't add the protein powder yet.
3. Put the lid on.
4. Start the blender.
5. While it is actively blending, remove the "plug" in the center of the lid. If your blender's lid doesn't have "plug" in it, carefully remove the lid.
6. Slowly pour the protein powder into the center of the swirling smoothie.

Comment: That's a great idea, will try tomorrow morning.